# How can I update data in volume after web project was updated?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx, flask

I have a Flask application + Gunicorn which I run inside docker container. I also have Nginx in another container and would like to serve static files (e.g. js files in static folder of Flask app), in order to do it I have to create volume and attach it to the static volume.

When I create volume and then run dockerized app (Flask + Gunicorn) there are no problems, js files are up-to-date.

Then I update app from Github (do `git pull projectname`, then do `docker build -t myapp .` and then I get a problem that files in volume are still the same. Note: this is not client side browser issue, js files are not changed in the volume.

The problem is not related to Ngnix, since it take place when Ngnix do not serve static files (I did not make the option in config yet, now it serve only ordinary requests).

**I found the following way to solve the issue:**

1. Stop container which use the volume (only Flask + Gunicorn app now, Nginx do not use the volume yet): `docker rm -f appname_container`
2. Remove the volume: ```docker volume rm flask_static_files_volume_name``
3. Recreate the volume: `docker volume create  flask_static_files_volume_name`
4. Then run the Flask app again: `docker run ... appname_container`

As a result of the 4 steps the volume is populated with updated versions of all files. I see correct js file versions.

I have to do the steps each time I update the project. As fare as I understand it is correct volume behavior to maintain files after container restart, but is there any better way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are in git and not that huge in size, I would not bother with volumes. Volumes are meant for data that move often like a database or maybe file uploaded by a customer.

For files under git with a clear versioning scheme, for me they are part of your code and thus don't need a volume. Just include them in the container without a volume and recreate the full container on new release.

This is how docker/kubernetes would expect it to be done. This way you can easily do canary testing, blue green or progressive rollout or even a rollback to a previous version. The files are really part of the versioning scheme of the application and that's better.

You can even with the concept of "gitopts" (https://www.weave.works/technologies/gitops/) to automatically update your containers on git change in the main repo.

Of course, if on the contrary a given version of the app can serve arbitrar files without any notion of code release, then you may want volumes likely with some sort of database.

Comment: Actually I agree with you that what is related to code itself should not be stored in volumes, but it is how the app was dockerized before I started to do deployment side of the project (before I wrote only backend Python code + some js small files), so I try to find out if there is any reason to serve js files with nginx and hereby store them in volumes.

Comment: Volume need to be managed by production guys in kubernetes or docker swarm. They would be backuped and all. That read add complexity for me. I would think of changing the containerization design as it shall be quite simple to get this files part of the container (maybe around the last layer).

Comment: You can actually use docker cp or run shell command from the container that will affect the volume data (like copy the new version of file and reference it with a symbolic link). But I am not fan of it at all

Comment: Well we have very small team, so I'll continue doing devops part for the project, to change file executing commands in containers sounds very manual solution on par with recreating volume when update files. If no other view I'll go with your advice and we'll stop serving js files with nginx dockerized proxy.

Comment: Well, I am now following your advice and do not use volumes to store js files. Check out other forums, but there is no solid solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, don't be afraid you do it the right way. Your files are actually part of the code so you treat them as code.

Comment: Also if you think nginx is more efficant to serve the files, you can alway create several containter from your git repo in your build system. One with nginx and the static files and one with the dynamic genarated content and put them inside the same pod in kubernetes/ But this complexify things and if I were you, I would do it only if I see a perf problem and can prove I get improved performance with a dedicated benchmark. let's not fix and make more complex what is not broken.